# discord.py bot commandinvokeerror

Tags: python, discord.py

my discord bot stopped working around an hour ago and whenever i type a command it gives me an error bot still goes online and prints message on startup any help is appreciated

my code linked below in txt file

https://mega.nz/folder/w5IRHIDQ#YE5nH2sXw7mSaEELbnmxDw

the error im getting is linked

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc0Yk.png

Comment: Along with external links, you are supposed to make the code and image part of the question too. Please edit your question and include the code and image in markdown syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to load some json which is invalid, double check your json syntax with your ide or another [Json Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)!